# How to save a view (with folds) into the file?

Tags: folding

I just recently learned how to use folds and I find it very useful. I have added a rule to automatically save the view with my folds when I'm editing the markdown files with the rule:

```
augroup QuickNotes
  au BufWinLeave *.md mkview
  au BufWinEnter *.md silent loadview
augroup END
```

But when I have saved it and copied a file somewhere the folds were there no more.

**My question is:**
Is it possible to save folds (the view) into the text file I'm editting?
If not then maybe I can write a rule that will save the view into something like `.%.view` (dot filename dot view) ?

**Extra curious:**
If I save the views to the default location- where is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `:mkview` a filename as argument:

```
augroup QuickNotes
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinLeave *.md execute "mkview! " . expand('<afile>:p:h') . "/." . expand('<afile>:t') . ".view"
```

and use `:source` instead of `:loadview`:

```
    autocmd BufWinEnter *.md execute "silent! source " . expand('%:p:h') . "/." . expand('%:t') . ".view"
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test this. Could you also elaborate on where views are saved by default?

Comment: I does save the view to the file but the view does not get reloaded later...

Comment: Without argument, `:mkview` and `:loadview` will work with the default location. If you want to make them work with a specific filename you must give it to them as argument.

Comment: yes, but how? for me `loadview` only takes one argument which is `[nr]`. Help says that : Load the view for the current file.  When [nr] is omitted, the view stored with ":mkview" is loaded. When [nr] is specified, the view stored with ":mkview [nr]" is loaded.

Comment: You can use `:source <path/to/view>`; the saved view is nothing but an auto-generated Vim script.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that information at `:help :mkview`:

```
:mkvie[w][!] [file] Write a Vim script that restores the contents of the
                        current window.
                        When [!] is included an existing file is overwritten.
                        When [file] is omitted or is a number from 1 to 9, a
                        name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended.  [...]
```

The generated filename has the full path of the original file encoded in it; that explains why it isn't loaded if you rename the original file.

So, you either need to move / copy the corresponding view file (found inside `'viewdir'`; default `~/.vim/view`), or `:source` it once to reapply the folds (then `:autocmd`s will then ensure the view gets persisted under the new file name).

The view always is a separate file; I would not recommend putting it into the same directory as the original file.

Comment: " I would not recommend putting it into the same directory as the original file."
...why?

Comment: @gojira: It just clutters the directory; you don't want to accidentally check it into version control, or upload it to a server. Also, unless you specify your own `file`, the view file name has the full original filespec encoded into it, so you cannot move both easily around, anyway (this is what my answer is about).