# How do I keep folds when formatting (reindenting) the whole file?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, indentation, external-command, folding

I do quite often use this mapping:

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> == :%!clang-format -style=file<cr>2g;zz
```

It reindents the whole file and returns the cursor to the last edit position.

Problem is, if I have folds, they get closed. All of them.

How do I keep each fold's state after this command? [Some suggest](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/how-to-save-a-view-with-folds-into-the-file) saving a session, but this seems inefficient, and in my case I neither close the file nor leave vim.

Comment: You could save only the view? (`:h :mkview`)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. And, it removes the need of `2g;zz`.

Comment: It's ok to accept your own answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> == :mkview<cr>:%!clang-format -style=file<cr>:loadview<cr>
```

Comment: I won't accept this answer as it's entirely based on others' suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Here's something that might solve the issue.
It's really a template of a possible solution (not actually tested).

```
function! ReindentMyCpp()
  mkview!
  execute 'normal! :nnoremap == :%!clang-format -style=file2g$' . "\r"
  execute 'normal zz'
  loadview
endfun

autocmd FileType cpp ReindentMyCpp()
```

BEFORE EDIT:

Here's some code that keeps the folds when you leave a buffer and restores it when you come back.

```
" save folds states in a file 'view'
set viewoptions=folds,cursor
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview!
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

This works well, and might somehow be adapted to your situation. It works of course if you have some `autocmd` that invokes `mkview` to save the fold's state before your own `autocmd` acts, and another that restores it afterwards.

I'm thinking you might want to define a function that does all three in a row (save the *view* in this way, do what your original `autocmd` did, then restore the *view* in this way), then have your `autocmd` invoke that function (as to save folds, do the indentation stuff, restore folds). I don't know if this will work for your problem, but it's probably worth a shot.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't leave buffers here. I just run `clang-format` and write it's output back to the file. I managed to keep the folds using `mkview` as @VanLaser proposed in his comment. I already saw such script in the linked question but didn't think I could use `mkview` that way.

Comment: What I'm really suggesting is this: use the `autocmd` that you have, but invoke `mkview` and `loadview` from it with your original code "sandwiched" in between. This would probably be better done with a function. In fact, I'm going to try to piece that function together and edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: As per your edit - this will reindent code only entering a cpp buffer. I'm using a mapping as I constantly need this; that's why I'm looking for something more efficient. With my current approach, there is a half-a-second full-screen blink. Not *that* bad, but could be better.