# How do you disable automatic code folding?

Tags: folding

I use `foldmethod=indent`but I hate how it starts each file pre-folded. To get around this I put `au BufWinEnter * normal zi` in my vimrc. That had worked fine so far, but now that I started using CoC, My error messages are getting auto-folded, which is obviously not what I want. I tried adding `MenuPopup` to the autocommand but no luck. How can I get this... window? (Idk what it is as far as Vim is concerned) to no automatically fold its text?

[image]

Comment: If the problem is that the files open pre-folded you can try this: [How to save a view (with folds) into the file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/how-to-save-a-view-with-folds-into-the-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `set nofoldenable` in your vimrc. This will also accomplish what your autocommand does.

Comment: This does indeed keep everything unfolded initially, but as soon as you toggle on one fold, that changes the value of `nofoldenable` and the entire file gets folded again.  That might be sufficient for certain use cases but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is probably the best place for this question, it has also been asked on other more popular sites:

- https://superuser.com/q/278442/9458
- https://superuser.com/q/169973/9458
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/8316139/120999

Answers generally fall into three categories.

The first is what has already been posted here, which is to `set nofoldenable`.  This on first glance appears to be correct, but it's an internal variable modified by the various fold commands.  The consequence of this is that as soon as you execute a fold command (for instance, `za`), `nofoldenable` is overwritten and all folds are collapsed.  This is probably not what you want.

The second is to use `BufRead` or similar to execute a folding command once you open a buffer.  This will work, but to my mind is more of a hack than option three.

Option three then being to utilize `foldlevelstart`.  Foldlevel is a variable that

> Sets the fold level: Folds with a higher level will be closed.
> Setting this option to zero will close all folds.  Higher numbers will
> close fewer folds.
> This option is set by commands like zm, zM and zR.

(Note that it *isn't* modified by smaller-scoped fold commands like `za`, like `nofoldenable` is.)

`foldlevelstart` then sets `foldlevel` when opening a buffer:

> Sets 'foldlevel' when starting to edit another buffer in a window.
> Useful to always start editing with all folds closed (value zero),
> some folds closed (one) or no folds closed (99).

This is all to say that you can use a snippet like this in your vimrc:

```
" Enable folding, but don't collapse folds by default.
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevelstart=99
```